# Excel Workbook Open Event macro doesn't always run

Tags: excel, events, vba, excel-2003

I've got a Workbook_Open event macro (and it's in ThisWorkbook) that doesn't always run.

- If Excel is closed and I double-click the .xls file from Windows Explorer, it does run.
- If I launch Excel from Start/Programs (with no .xls file) and then open the file, it does run.
- If I've already opened the file in Excel, but then close the file (leaving Excel open) and reopen it, then the macro does not run.

I've got security set to medium and I enable macros whenever it opens.

What do I need to do to get the macro to run whenever I open it, not just the first time for this Excel session?

(btw, this is Excel 2003)

Comment: All I can tell you is that it does work in Excel 2010 :(

Comment: Do you have a Workbook_BeforeClose event?

Comment: After you open the workbook in case 3, will any other macros work?

Comment: I've run a quick test of the three scenarios you describe (in excel 2003) and all three run the open event.  therefore there must be something else going on with your file and or installation.  pls post further details of any other code in your file and any other installations you mey have (eg any installed excel addins)

Comment: Workbook_BeforeClose: No, I don't.

Comment: @Lance-Roberts After I open the workbook in all 3 cases, other macros do work.

Comment: @chris-neilsen: Excel add-ins: Analysis ToolPak, Analysis ToolPak - VBA, Conditional Sum Wizard, Euro Currency Tools, Internet Assistant VBA, Lookup Wizard, Solver Add-in all show up in Tools / Add-ins, but none of them are checked. There's lots of other code in the macros, but none gets executed in case 3 -- I put a msgbox in there and it didn't come up.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I thought that this was [the most cogent article](http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/excel-prog/45324/Workbook-Open-event-does-not-fire) on this problem (which is a long-standing never explained completely erratic bug that Excel exhibits).</strike> (dead link)

In short, in many cases it's a timing thing caused because the workbook is trying to calculate stuff when it opens and that gets in the way of the Workbook_Open event.  The way to test on yours to see if that it for this situation, is to first rename any UDFs or Macros called by cells so that they won't get called and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Maybe changing the calculation to manual couldn't do the trick as well?

Comment: I just tried adding the code from the article you mentioned; didn't seem to help. :-( And there's a whole lot of tabs and a lot of code...hard to rename everything...any suggestions on how to start?

Comment: Oh -- but thanks very much for posting the link to that article! Good to know that I'm not alone in this!

Comment: @ScottSM, I'd see if I could find a way to completely disable calculation when the worksheet opened up and see if that helped.  I'm not sure off-hand how to do this when the Workbook Opens, but maybe some research will turn up a way.  You might be able to copy one Tab at a time to a blank workbook, and see if any particular one is causing the Workbook_Open event not to fire.  Of course with interrelations between sheets, that's not always so easy.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem.

I tested a workbook on my computer without any troubles. After destributing it to my customers I was told, that some combo-boxes stayed empty. These are usually filled from inside the `workbook_open` routine.
I tried different things to enable the `workbook_open`-Event - without success.

Finally, I found that disabling all userdefined Functions (UDF) lead to correct execution of `workbook_open`.

As my workbook is opened from another file, I will try to set calculation to manual first and then run the `workbook_open` manually. This may be done by defining it

```
public sub workbook_open
```

instead of

```
private sub workbook_open
```

Strange, that excel does not time this by itself...

Comment: I came up with a solution considering an answer to a similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006902/workbook-open-is-not-executed-with-excel-already-running). A private boolean variable in the workbook is used to determine if the workbook_open event was fired. If not the I added handlers to workbook_activate and to workbook_sheet_change and rerun the workbook_open event if the variable was not set.

Answer (score 2):

A late answer (better than none).

I've had this problem now a few times (with Excel 2010). 
The solution that has always worked (so far) was: remove conditional formatting, in particular if it contains UDF as conditions. As @LanceRoberts wrote in an above post, it's ultimately due to UDF calculations "overriding" the Open event, but I've found that those are particularly harmful if used in conditional formats.

Comment: Spot on - removing UDF used in conditional formatting solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing almost identical behavior, and found that it is due to a bug that occurs if conditional formatting rules are erroring out. It turns out that if the conditional formatting rules are based on any setup by the macros, and that causes the conditional formatting to error, the Workbook_Open macro will not even attempt to run.

To test, make a copy of your file, and delete all conditional formatting from the workbook.  Save and reopen.  If it fixes your issue, then rework the conditional formatting rules to not depend on functions/values that will be broken before the Workbook_Open macro runs.

Comment: But I need My conditional formatting. How can I keep it from doing it's thing until after the file is loaded.

Comment: There appears to be no way to do that.  Again, if you wright your conditional rules to not depend on those values which are macro dependent (which can typically be done if you think through the problem, but is specific to each case) you can get the issue resolved.  Deleting the conditional formatting is just a testing step to identify the specific formatting rule creating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the Arturo Llano post: The following code was used to monitor the Workbook_Open event and then run ProcessX whenever a workbook was opened.

ProcessX contained an End statement. The result was that it worked only the first time. The End wiped out AppX, so there was no further monitoring of events. Removing End fixed the problem. (Using End is bad practice anyway as it stops everything without any kind of cleanup or termination of other resources).

'Code in: Personal.xlsb ThisWorkbook

```
Public WithEvents AppX As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Set AppX = Application

End Sub

Private Sub AppX_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook)

  'A 1-second delay to allow opening to complete before ProcessX starts.

   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "ProcessX"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Try signing the workbook with a digital certificate. Add this certificate to the Trusted Certificates store then try again.
2. If this is machine-specific, try re-installing Office.

Make sure you have the latest service pack(s) applied.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and I avoid it using the security settings.
I use the options settings then confidentiality center, then "params of confidentiality center" (sorry but its a translation of the french version :-p)
then "files approuved" or something like this.
And add the file containing the excel workbook in.
And its finnaly worked after that.

Looked everywhere and never find that solution.

Hope it'll help someone

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a workbook is closed with an Application.EnableEvents set to false, and then you open another workbook within the same instance of excel opened. To avoid this, make sure that all of your processes that disable events, reenable them before terminating. Special attention to "End" commands, error handlers and "exit sub" sentences in the middle of your program.

Answer (score 0):

What causes it is that your other archive, the one you openned first, have a  `Workbook_Open` procedure; Excel doesn't excute it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also and took me hours to figure out.

Turns out the **TODAY()** function in Excel was causing the problem.
Once deleted from my worksheet everything worked again. Very strange bug.