# Code only runs on Excel 2007 if file is opened from within Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2013, vba

I have some relatively simple code that loops through multiple files in a folder, opens each and copies a range of data into a new worksheet.  I wrote the code using Excel 2013.  Some users have 2007 on their box.  If the 2007 users open the file from within Excel (i.e File-Open, and navigate to the directory), it runs fine.  If the 2007 users open the file from Windows Explorer, all the macros run, except the file name variable "myFile" that I use in the loop is always EMPTY. It's like it won't navigate to the directory.  I do not get any errors, it just executes the code and goes right to the end of the loop (which says to stop when "myFile" is empty) -- then continues on with the next macro.  With Excel 2013, the program runs fine regardless of how it is opened.  I thought my answer might have been contained in this thread:  [Excel Workbook Open Event macro doesn't always run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438548/excel-workbook-open-event-macro-doesnt-always-run)  but the Q&A doesn't seem to apply directly to my issue since the macros actually run.  It seems to be just the navigation to the file location that won't work. Here is the snippet of code that runs the loop:

```
    Dim myfile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DataBlock As Range

'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set wb = Workbooks("ComboFile.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")    'change desired sheet

ChDir "r:\BSI\Sys9000"
myfile = Dir("*.xlsx")

Do Until myfile = ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
    Set DataBlock = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    DataBlock.Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Windows(myfile).Close
    myfile = Dir
Loop

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Any suggestions welcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you replace this:

```
ChDir "r:\BSI\Sys9000"
myfile = Dir("*.xlsx")
```

with just this:

```
myfile = Dir("r:\BSI\Sys9000\*.xlsx")
```

`ChDir` won't change drives so if the current directory is not on the R drive, the code would fail.

You will also need to change this:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile
```

to include the path:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="r:\BSI\Sys9000\" & myfile
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your code.  It worked fine on Excel 2013, but on Excel 2007 it now stops with an error.  It's strange.  it says it can't find file 701.xlsx file ("maybe it's been moved" comment).  How would it even know to look for that file, which does happen to be in that directory location?  I also tried replacing the r:\ with the full server file path.  Same result. @rory

Comment: This worked THANK YOU!  Why do I need to specify the path again inside the loop?  Does it default (sometimes... and only for Excel 2007) back to a default directory every time a Workbook.Open  is issued?  Or if there's another reason you thought to do this let me know.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It defaults to whatever the current directory is unless you specify a path.