# Can I force an Excel "Workbook_open" event via a button click

Tags: vba, excel, events, event-handling

I know there are a number of threads on the topic of the `Workbook_open` event not always firing. Seems disabling UDFs might work as might digital certificates.

See [Excel Workbook Open Event macro doesn't always run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438548/excel-workbook-open-event-macro-doesnt-always-run)

But why would adding a digital certificate help?

As an alternate solution I wondered if there might be a way to force the `Workbook_open` event to fire via a button click? This way a user could refresh the on screen combo boxes etc when the initial open event fails.

I've tried adding `Workbook_open` as part of a button click, but get a `"Sub or Function not defined"` error. I suppose this is no great surprise as this event belongs to the "ThisWorkbook" object!

`ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` does not work.

Note: I've added extra coded items to a combo box in the `Workbook_open` event so I'm expecting these to appear if I can get the refresh to work!

Comment: Declare the `Workbook_open` handler as `Public`.

Comment: Many thanks @Gserg! Changing the `Workbook_open` to `Public Sub Workbook_open()` and then adding the following button click event works `Private Sub Cmd_Refresh_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Workbook_open
End Sub`

Comment: You can also just use `Run` without making it public: `Application.Run "ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open"`

Comment: Thanks @Rory! This possibly works better than using a `Public Sub` for the `Workbook Open` event, as I've noticed that the automatic execution of the `Workbook Open` event is not as reliable when 'Public'. Not sure why this should be the case? However, `Application.Run"ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open"` appears to work all the time!

Comment: It's probably worth specifying the workbook too, just for safety: `Application.Run "'" & thisworkbook.name & "'!ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open"`

Comment: Why not wrap the code in the `Workbook_Open` function in a sub. Call that sub in the `Workbook_Open` function and then you can call the sub anywhere.